# RxJava2 - Subscribing PublishSubject

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

```
 private val searchSubject =  PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun textChange(){
    searSubject.onNext(true)
}

fun getSubject(){
    compositeDisposable += searchSubject
        .doOnNext {
            if (it) showLoading()
        }
        .switchMap { searchGithubReposObservable() }
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<List<GithubRepo>>() {
            override fun onNext(t: List<GithubRepo>) {
                hideLoading()
                adapter.items = t
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                hideLoading()
            }
        })
}
```

- searchGithubReposObservable is the fucntion that returns the `Observable<List<GithubRepo>>`

I searched the sample code in the github for studying RxJava.
However, I can't understand the above code.

I know that to receive data from PublishSubject, I need to subscribe it.

In the above code, I thought that `subscribeWith` subscribes searchGithubReposObservable()'s return Observable , but I could get the data from PublishSubject when the textchange() is called.

Why is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of your RX chain you are listening to the publish subject.

```
compositeDisposable += searchSubject
    .doOnNext {
        if (it) showLoading()
    }
```

Each time you call method `textChange()` you push to searchSubject which fires the RX chain all over again trigging the switchmap.

Comment: Oh, I got it. 
So, perhaps subscribeWtih method is applied to searchSubject.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible you can get the data when textchange() method is getting called i have implemented this type of functionality while i was typing text api got called on textchange and i received data Below code.

I have written please check

```
 autocompletetextview.debounce(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .filter { it.trim().isNotEmpty() || it.isEmpty() }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .flatMap {
                        Observable.just(callapi here )
                    }
                    .subscribe({
                        it.subscribe({ serviceResponse ->
                            if (serviceResponse.meta.status == KeyUtils.HTTP_SUCCESS ||
                                    serviceResponse.meta.status == KeyUtils.STATUS_META_ERROR) {
                                setSuccessResponse(serviceResponse, true)
                            } else {
                                setSuccessResponse(serviceResponse, false)
                            }
                        }, { throwable ->
                            setErrorResponse(throwable)
                        }).collect()
```

Comment: Oh, sorry.
I mean why did my code work?
To explain in detail, why can I get the data from PublishSubject.
I thought that I subcribed the searchGithubReposObservable() method not PublishSubject.